# SSL integration for Node.js app behind AWS ELB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, lets-encrypt

I have AWS instances (behind a load balancer) serving a Node.js / Express app for mobile clients. I would like to enable SSL for the API calls on this app. There are multiple tutorials on how to enhance my Express app to use SSL, but can can folks advise please what should be the ELB configuration in such a scenario?

Should I have the ELB listeners (both load-balancer side as well as instance-side) to be http (not https)? And then make the Node.js app use a certificate from say LetsEncrypt?

Or should I instead have the load balancer be https based (and thus have its own associated certificate from AWS Certificate Manager)? In that case, what happens to the LetsEncrypt certificate - do I still integrate that with the Node.js app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You would enable SSL on the load balancer and use an ACM certificate. You wouldn't need a SSL certificate on the NodeJS server unless you just want the communication between the ELB and the server to also be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B - much appreciated. For my understanding, if I do need the backend authentication (not that I really do!), would the client app have to reflect that in any way? I.e. I'm confused as to what changes in the client if the ELB and the backend both have their own certificates? Also, how would communication from the backend server to the client get encrypted (the ELB and the backend authentication play no role there) - apologies - rather basic SSL-related / off-topic questions.... thanks again....

Comment: The client would be completely unaffected by backend encryption. Only the ELB would need to know about the backend encryption, and you would do that by simply changing the port/protocol in the ELB configuration that it uses to communicate with the backend.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about communication between the backend and the client, when you say "the ELB and the backend authentication play no role there". Do you have communication happening between the client and the backend that doesn't go through the load balancer somehow?

Comment: Makes sense now @Mark B ... using your comments and some further reading, I now better understand the options here. You're right - there's no direct comm. between the client and the backend. Just to confirm what I understand, could you pls. review the below alternatives pls! Many thanks again!
1. Use SSL termination at the ELB. What you are recommending...
2. Enable SSL termination at the ELB and then force re-encryption between ELB and back-end using back-end authentication. I can use a LetsEncrypt certificate on the backend here.
3. Use SSL pass-through, with no ELB authentication.

Comment: 3. Contd.

From what I understand, it is not possible to implement SSL-passthrough with ELB and HTTP because the ELB wouldn't be able to decrypt and understand the message type. So to achieve that, we either remove the ELB and use a single Node.js server, or implement SSL-passthrough only for TCP-connected apps via the ELB.

Sorry for the multiple questions - just trying to clarify my understanding here so that I can architect the solution correctly!

Many thanks again!